# Sufficient condition on $(z_n)_n$ such that $f(z_n)=g(z_n)$ for every $n$ implies $f=g$ for $f$ and $g$ holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to do the following exercice:

> Let $(z_n)_{n\geq 0}$ be a sequence of distinct points from an open set $\Omega\subset\mathbb{C}$. Find a sufficient condition on the sequence $(z_n)_{n\geq 0}$ such that the following property holds:
>   $$\forall f,g\in\text{Hol}(\Omega),\qquad (f(z_n)=g(z_n),\quad\forall n\in\mathbb{N})\quad\implies\quad (f=g\:\text{ over }\:\Omega).$$

I know that if $\Omega$ is connected, then it is enough that such sequence has a limit point. But I don't have that $\Omega$ is connected. Is there any other known condition?

Comment: Perhaps you can use that $\Omega$ is an union of it's connected components?

Comment: Lets suppose that $\Omega=U\cup V$, where $U$ and $V$ are connected. If $\{z_n\}\subset U$, and this sequence has a limit point, then we have that $f=g$ over $U$, which is weaker than what we want.

Comment: That's true, you need that $z_n$ splits among all connected components. In your example, it means that you can find disjoint sequences $z_{n_k}\subseteq U$ and $z_{n_l}\subseteq V$ each with a limit point. (I don't see any relations between $f|_U$ and $f|_V$ so this seems to be the best condition). In simple words "$z_n$ has a limit point in each of the connected components of $\Omega$".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A sufficient, and NECESSARY condition is that the sequence $\{z_n\}$ possesses at least one limit point in every connected component of $\Omega$.

Necessity. If $U$ is a connected component and $\{z_n\}\subset U$ without limit point in $U$, then Weierstrass Factorisation Theorem (its version for non-entire functions) implies that there exist infinitely many analytic functions in $U$, which agree in the $z_n$'s.

Comment: Can you say a little more about why it is a necessary condition?

Comment: @GabrielRibeiro See my edited answer.